# keydown only when input is not in focus

Tags: jquery, keydown

Currently I've setup a function to go forward and back when pressing the left and right arrow keys in pages using this:

```
$(document).keydown(function (e) {
    if ($(e.target).is('input')) { return false
    } else if (e.keyCode == 37) {
        $(".pageback").click();
        return false;
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 39) {
        $(".pagenext").click();
        return false;
    }
});
```

This allows the arrow keys to be used to browse back and forth, but when a textbox is encountered, the arrow keys are still active.

Although this stops the keydown functions when the textbox is in focus, it also does not allow anything at all to be typed into the input area.

HELP!

Thanks

Comment: Please don't post your code all on one line, it is too difficult to follow.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> *"it also does not allow anything at all to be typed into the input area."*

The problem is this part:

```
if ($(e.target).is('input')) { return false
```

When you return `false` from the event handler it prevents the default behaviour for the event.

Change it to `return true` or just `return` (with no value) and the default behaviour (in this case, typing in the field) will be permitted.

(Note: you may also want to check for textarea elements, not just inputs.)

Comment: awesome thank-you. Would it be possible to also add a short say 200 ms delay between key presses for the left and right keys?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean about adding a delay, unless you mean you want to prevent more than one arrow-key press within 200ms? (But in my opinion that would be another question, and you should have a go at implementing it yourself first.)

Comment: I know, i've tried using a setTimeout function, just don't know where in this it needs to be added that's all.

Answer (score 2):

My approach is to check if the target is `document.body` on `keydown`, then wait for `keyup`.

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(keyEvent) {
  if (keyEvent.key != 'ArrowLeft' || keyEvent.shiftKey || keyEvent.ctrlKey || keyEvent.altKey || keyEvent.metaKey) {
    return
  }
  if (keyEvent.target != document.body) {
    return
  }
  
  keyEvent.preventDefault()
  
  // myButton.classList.add('active') // visual feedback a button has been triggered

  document.addEventListener('keyup', function(keyEvent) {
    keyEvent.preventDefault()
    
    // do your stuff
  })
})
```